# Legend items to appear / disappear simultaneaously with Layer turned on/off in Layer Control

Tags: leaflet, legend

I have a number of layers that can be turned on and off with a Layer Control.
I’d like the description of each layer to show in the legend if it's turned on.
And disappear again as soon as the layer is turned off in the layer control.

I am new to js and Leaflet.

Comment: So this question was put back into circulation 2.5 years after it was asked, then 3 hours ago slammed with a hold. I was under the impression StackExchange was there to help people but recently I'm seeing a lot of holds put on by someone hiding behind the off-topic definition. Some have been easy questions with easy answers but the reviewer didn't understand the question and generated a quick hold. Some deserve a hold being too vague but some questions are asked because they don't know where to start. Instead of help I think we wrongly turn off a lot of programmers from using StackExchange.

Comment: I want to be clear I'm not pointing at anyone in particular, it's just a general trend, and it's a great resource to use. It's helped me and allowed me to help others.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any built-in functionality or plugins for this, but here is a solution that should get you started (using jQuery). In short, because the Layer Control is generating dynamic html, we use jQuery to select the leaflet control layers overlays, and add a description. Then make use of [these built in Leaflet map events](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers-baselayerchange) to show and hide the description when a user turns on/off a layer.

Building from [this example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html), we add a couple of new functions to show/hide a description:

```
function showDescription() {
    var target = $('.leaflet-control-layers-overlays');
    var div = $('<div>', {}).appendTo(target);
    var html = $('<p>',{text: "This is a description for the cities layer"}).appendTo(div);
}

// ititialize. Since we've added cities to the map, we know its visible: show the description
showDescription();

// on map layer change, hide or show the description div
map.on('overlayadd', function(){ $('.leaflet-control-layers-overlays div').show() });
map.on('overlayremove', function(){ $('.leaflet-control-layers-overlays div').hide() });
```

Full example below. This code should run locally if you save to a file (e.g. index.html) and load in your browser with `file:///C:/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leaflet Layers Control Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>

    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script>
        var cities = new L.LayerGroup();

        L.marker([39.61, -105.02]).bindPopup('This is Littleton, CO.').addTo(cities),
        L.marker([39.74, -104.99]).bindPopup('This is Denver, CO.').addTo(cities),
        L.marker([39.73, -104.8]).bindPopup('This is Aurora, CO.').addTo(cities),
        L.marker([39.77, -105.23]).bindPopup('This is Golden, CO.').addTo(cities);


        var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            mbUrl = 'https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';

        var grayscale   = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'examples.map-20v6611k', attribution: mbAttr}),
            streets  = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'examples.map-i875mjb7',   attribution: mbAttr});

        var map = L.map('map', {
            center: [39.73, -104.99],
            zoom: 10,
            layers: [grayscale, cities]
        });

        var baseLayers = {
            "Grayscale": grayscale,
            "Streets": streets
        };

        var overlays = {
            "Cities": cities
        };

        L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);

        // everything above here is from this example: http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html. Below, I've added a couple of new functions
        function showDescription() {
            var target = $('.leaflet-control-layers-overlays');
            var div = $('<div>', {}).appendTo(target);
            var html = $('<p>',{text: "This is a description for this layer"}).appendTo(div);
        }
        // ititialize. Since we've added cities to the map, we know its visible: show the description
        showDescription();

        // on map layer change. Here we want to test the layer visibility, and hide or show the description div
        map.on('overlayadd', function(){ $('.leaflet-control-layers-overlays div').show() });
        map.on('overlayremove', function(){ $('.leaflet-control-layers-overlays div').hide() });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```